# JavaScript time in text field and not updating

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this JavaScript inst placing the time within the blank text field and updating the time every second. I am trying to get the JavaScript to have a label at the top that says Current Time then a text field that has the current time that is updated every second.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var dateform
speed=2000
tid=0;
function dodate()
{
f.date.value=new Date();
tid=window.setTimeout("dodate()",speed);
}
function start(x)
{
  f=x 
  tid=window.setTimeout("dodate()",speed);
}
function cleartid()
{
  window.clearTimeout(tid);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="start(document.dateform) ;">
<center>
The Digital Clock
<FORM name="dateform" action="post">
<input type="text" name="date" size=30>
</FORM>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you need to use is `setInterval` and make little changes:

```
var dateform
speed=1000
tid=0;
function dodate()
{
f.date.value=new Date();
}
function start(x)
{
  f=x 
  tid=window.setInterval("dodate()",speed);
}
function cleartid()
{
  window.clearTimeout(tid);
}
```

Comment: Ok so it works, I was trying to use n2j.com to view the code and output and it wasnt showing it properly. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: That worked, thank you both. I cant "Answer Your Question" Once I can, I will add your answer ifm.